# How do I calculate overlapping date ranges duration (more than 2) with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am trying to calculate the global duration of many date ranges.

In my DB I have candidates and experiences.

A candidate may have many experiences, and an experience has a start date and may have a end_date or not.

Experiences date ranges can overlap, here I am stuck, how to calculate the duration ?

This is how I join my models:

[image: My models]

I want to retrieve a list of candidates by querying the experiences and skills:
I have 2 inputs, the range and the skill name. For example, I want all the candidates having the skill 'Ruby' through experiences and experiences_skills with experience global duration of 5 years.

### EDIT

Current solution:

```
      SELECT * FROM (
            WITH cte AS (
                SELECT
                  experiences.candidate_id AS candidate_id,
                  experiences.id AS e_id,
                  experiences.start_at AS start_at,
                  experiences.end_at AS end_at,
                  LAG(experiences.start_at, 1, start_at)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY experiences.candidate_id ORDER BY experiences.start_at) AS prev_start_at,
                  LAG(experiences.end_at, 1, start_at)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY experiences.candidate_id ORDER BY experiences.start_at) AS prev_end_at,
                  LEAD(experiences.start_at)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY experiences.candidate_id ORDER BY experiences.start_at) AS next_start_at,
                  LEAD(experiences.end_at, 1, current_date)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY experiences.candidate_id ORDER BY experiences.start_at) AS next_end_at
                FROM experiences
                  INNER JOIN experiences_skills ON experiences_skills.experience_id = experiences.id
                  INNER JOIN skills ON skills.id = experiences_skills.skill_id
                WHERE skills.name = 'Ruby'
            )
            SELECT
              SUM(CASE
                  WHEN (cte.prev_end_at > cte.end_at AND cte.prev_end_at < cte.next_start_at)
                    THEN cte.prev_end_at
                  WHEN (cte.prev_end_at > cte.end_at AND cte.prev_end_at > cte.next_start_at)
                    THEN cte.next_start_at
                  WHEN cte.end_at > cte.next_start_at
                    THEN cte.next_start_at
                  ELSE cte.end_at
                  END
                  -
                  cte.start_at
              ) AS duration_day,
              candidates.*
            FROM cte
              INNER JOIN candidates ON candidates.id = cte.candidate_id
            GROUP BY candidates.id
          ) AS candidates
      WHERE duration_day > 0 AND duration_day < 1000';
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results will be helpful

Comment: Ok, I will add this in 5 minutes

Comment: So, if I'm getting this right, a candidate can have multiple experiences in the same skill, which may (or may not) overlap & you want the sum of these experiences' length (without the overlapping parts)? -- So, in your example, if a candidate has 2 experiences for the skill of *Ruby*: f.ex. `2010-2013` and `2011-2014` and you query for a global duration of *5 years*, then that candidate is not eligible, because (without overlaps) he/she has experience with the skill from 2010 to 2014 (which is only 4 years)?

Comment: Also, if an experience ha no `end_at`, you would calculate with `current_timestamp` I assume (or `current_date` maybe? What is the exact type of `end_at`?). An open range wouldn't make much sense, because it's length is infinite (which would be always greater than a queried, finite *global duration*).

Comment: Exactly, let me post my current solution for this. See my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can solve this without [defining your own aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html), like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION range_array_merge(s anyarray, v anynonarray)
    RETURNS anyarray
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
AS $func$
  WITH RECURSIVE arrays(r) AS (
      SELECT s || v
    UNION ALL
      SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT u)
      FROM   (SELECT a + b u
              FROM   arrays,
                     unnest(r) a
              JOIN   unnest(r) b ON a <> b AND a && b) u
      HAVING COUNT(u) > 0
  ),
  ranges(r) AS (
      SELECT unnest(r)
      FROM   arrays
  )
  SELECT    array_agg(DISTINCT r.r)
  FROM      ranges r
  LEFT JOIN ranges c ON c.r <> r.r AND c.r @> r.r
  WHERE     c.r IS NULL
$func$;

CREATE AGGREGATE range_array_merge_agg(anynonarray) (
  STYPE    = anyarray,
  SFUNC    = range_array_merge(anyarray, anynonarray),
  INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

This can collect any type of ranges & will accumulate them into a single array, which will have only separate ranges (overlapping ranges are union-ed together).

With this, your query is as "simple" as:

```
SELECT   e.candidate_id,
         SUM(upper(r.r) - lower(r.r) + 1) total_days
FROM     (SELECT   e.candidate_id,
                   range_array_merge_agg(daterange(e.start_at, COALESCE(e.end_at, current_date))) r
          FROM     experiences e
          JOIN     experiences_skills es ON es.experience_id = e.id
          WHERE    es.skill_id = 42 --> search for a specific skill
          GROUP BY e.candidate_id) e,
         unnest(e.r) r
GROUP BY e.candidate_id;
```

Assuming `start_at` and `end_at` has type of `date`. With the `timestamp [with time zone]` type, things will get messy, but I doubt that you would ever need that precision.

You could filter the query above with simply `HAVING SUM(upper(r.r) - lower(r.r) + 1) > 1000`.

http://rextester.com/DNSWS30622

**Edit**: to search for complete candidate rows:

```
SELECT   c.*
FROM     (SELECT   e.candidate_id,
                   range_array_merge_agg(daterange(e.start_at, COALESCE(e.end_at, current_date))) r
          FROM     experiences e
          JOIN     experiences_skills es ON es.experience_id = e.id
          WHERE    es.skill_id = 42 --> search for a specific skill
          GROUP BY e.candidate_id) e,
         unnest(e.r) r
JOIN     candidates c ON e.candidate_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING   SUM(upper(r.r) - lower(r.r) + 1) > 1000; --> search for minimum number of total days
```

**Note**: if you ever wonder why is a `+ 1` in the sum, the reason is simple. `date '2017-01-01' - date '2017-01-01'` is `0` (zero). While I consider this as *1 day of experience* (that day would be exactly `2017-01-01`). So that's why the sum needs `+ 1`. You can also express this in the `daterange` constructor, like: `daterange(e.start_at, COALESCE(e.end_at, current_date)), '[]')`. But because of `date` is discrete, a `[2017-01-01,2017-01-02]` range will be canonicalized to the `[2017-01-01,2017-01-03)` form. That way there would be no need to add `1` to the sum, because canonicalization already "extends" its `upper()` bound.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer ! I will try it ASAP. Since your tests return the expected results, I validate your answer

Comment: This is a smart answer, yet I am unable to gather a list of candidates with it. Your query will send me only ids with duration, it allows me to filter it by duration but I'm not sure about how to get candidates.* without bloating your query.

Comment: @TerryRaimondo you can join `candidates` into the outer query `ON candidates.id = e.candidate_id`, use `GROUP BY candidates.id` instead of `e.candidate_id` (they will be the same anyway) and because `candidates.*` depends on `candidates.id` functionally (it is the primary key of the table), you can select `candidates.*` in the outer query. And you don't have to select `total_days` if you only want to filter it.

Comment: Sir, you saved my day. May you live long.

Comment: I changed the order of your Implicit/Explicit joins. I ran into the issue :)

Answer (score -1):

I cant find the primary key of your experiences_skills table because experience_id and skill_id both are FK.

To avoid this problem you can remove experiences_skills table and add PK of candidates table into experiences_skills and skills table as FK, and try below query:

```
select * from candidates c, exp e, skills s where c.candid = e.candid and c.candid = s.candid and (datediff(year,e.sdate, e.edate) = 1) and s.name = 'test'
```

Now below is the image of table structures:

[image]

Comment: Better is to use JOIN form